# How to st_read a .shp-file from a subfolder in a .zip-file without unzipping it in R?

Tags: r

i try to read a .shp file from a subfolder in a .zip file without unzipping it.
I tried

```
con <- unz(description = "C:/Test/File.zip", filename = "subfolder/shape.shp")
db <- st_read(con)
```

but it failed in some way and receive this message.

```
Cannot open; The file doesn't seem to exist.
```

Any advise?

Comment: You are assuming that `st_read` can handle arbitrary connections, but that is not what its documentation says. It can take a character naming a file, a DBIobject, a PostgreSQLConnection or a Pool object. I don't think there is a straighforward way of getting it to read an `unz` connection.